# Stored procedure with MVC with input parameter and get output with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

This is an ASP.NET MVC project to execute stored procedure with input value, once we give input values, results will be shown in nested view. And the table doesn't have a primary key. So, while adding to Entity Framework, I am getting an error that I cannot add model designer to that stored procedure.

I haven't tried any code, because I am confused about how to add that stored procedure with table to project which is not having primary key.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CrystalBall_TAT_Computation] 
    (@Rescu_ID VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    -- Drop Temp Tables
    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#ClosedData','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#ClosedData;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_RESCU_Group','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_RESCU_GD_Group','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_GD_Group;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_PR_Count','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_PR_Count;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_GD_Count','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_GD_Count;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenRESCU_GD_Count','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenRESCU_GD_Count;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Final_Data','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#Final_Data;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#GD_Level_Calc','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#GD_Level_Calc;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#PR_Level_Calc','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#PR_Level_Calc;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Rescu_Level_Calc','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#Rescu_Level_Calc;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#RESCU_Sample','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#RESCU_Sample;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_PR','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_PR;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#PR_Sample','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#PR_Sample;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_GD','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_GD;

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#GD_Sample','U') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE dbo.#GD_Sample;


    DECLARE @ReportDate DATE;

    SELECT @ReportDate = MAX(CONVERT(DATE, Report_Date)) 
    FROM dbo.Rescue_Daily_Assiginment_File;

    -- Fetching relevant data from Open File for supplied RESCU ID
    SELECT
        A.NEW_RESCU_ID as RESCU_ID,
        A.PAR_REQ_REF_NBR as PR_ID,
        A.REQ_REF_NBR As GD_ID,
        A.RGN_CD, A.ST_CD, A.SBJ_CD,
        A.PRIMARYTRANSACTIONGROUP,
        A.PLATFORMSIMPACTED_TEXT,
        A.GENERAL_WORKTYPE,
        A.ON_OFF,
        CONVERT(DATE, A.GD_CRE_DT) AS GD_CRE_DT,
        ISNULL(A.RGN_CD, '') + ISNULL(A.ST_CD, '') + ISNULL(A.SBJ_CD, '') + ISNULL(A.PRIMARYTRANSACTIONGROUP, '') + ISNULL(A.PLATFORMSIMPACTED_TEXT, '') + ISNULL(A.GENERAL_WORKTYPE, '') + ISNULL(A.ON_OFF, '') AS Combine_ID
    INTO    
        dbo.#OpenData
    FROM
        dbo.Rescue_Daily_Assiginment_File AS A
    WHERE   
        A.NEW_RESCU_ID IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Rescue_Daily_Assiginment_File AS B 
                    WHERE A.NEW_RESCU_ID = B.NEW_RESCU_ID AND B.ESCL_IND_CD LIKE 'RESCU%')
        AND NEW_RESCU_ID = @Rescu_ID    -- '19137-19137'
        AND CONVERT(Date, A.Report_Date) = '2019-02-22' -- @ReportDate;

    ----------------
    -- GD Count
    SELECT
        MIN(A.GD_CRE_DT) AS RESCU_Create_Date,
        A.RESCU_ID,
        A.PR_ID,
        COUNT(A.GD_ID) AS Total_GDs
    INTO
        dbo.#OpenData_GD_Count
    FROM
        (SELECT
             GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID, GD_ID 
         FROM
             dbo.#OpenData 
         GROUP BY 
             GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID, GD_ID) AS A
    GROUP BY
        A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID;


    -- PR Count
    SELECT
        MIN(GD_CRE_DT) AS RESCU_Create_Date,
        A.RESCU_ID,
        COUNT(PR_ID) AS Total_PRs,
        MAX(Total_GDs) AS Total_GDs
    INTO    
        dbo.#OpenData_PR_Count
    FROM
        (SELECT
             GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID 
         FROM
             dbo.#OpenData 
         GROUP BY 
             GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID) AS A
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             RESCU_ID, SUM(Total_GDs) AS Total_GDs 
         FROM
             dbo.#OpenData_GD_Count 
         GROUP BY 
             RESCU_ID) AS B ON A.RESCU_ID = B.RESCU_ID
    GROUP BY 
        A.RESCU_ID;

    ----------------

    Select GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID, Combine_ID into dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group from dbo.#OpenData GROUP BY GD_CRE_DT, RESCU_ID, PR_ID, Combine_ID;

    Select RESCU_ID, PR_ID, GD_ID, Combine_ID into dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_GD_Group from dbo.#OpenData GROUP BY RESCU_ID, PR_ID, GD_ID, Combine_ID;

--**************** CALCULATION **********************
    SELECT  A.RESCU_ID
            , MAX(A.GD_CRE_DT) AS RESCU_Create_Date
            , MAX(C.Total_PRs) AS Total_PRs
            , MAX(C.Total_GDs) AS Total_GDs
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MIN_TAT, 0)) AS MIN_TAT
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MAX_TAT, 0)) AS MAX_TAT
    INTO    dbo.#Rescu_Level_Calc
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
            INNER JOIN dbo.#OpenData_PR_Count AS C
                ON A.RESCU_ID = C.RESCU_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID;


-- PR Level Output
    SELECT  A.RESCU_ID
            , A.PR_ID
            , MAX(C.Total_GDs) AS Total_GDs
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MIN_TAT, 0)) AS MIN_TAT
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MAX_TAT, 0)) AS MAX_TAT
    INTO    dbo.#PR_Level_Calc
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_GD_Group AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
            INNER JOIN dbo.#OpenData_GD_Count AS C
                ON A.RESCU_ID = C.RESCU_ID
                AND A.PR_ID = C.PR_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID;


-- GD Level Output
    SELECT  A.RESCU_ID
            , A.PR_ID
            , A.GD_ID
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MIN_TAT, 0)) AS MIN_TAT
            , MAX(ISNULL(B.MAX_TAT, 0)) AS MAX_TAT
    INTO    dbo.#GD_Level_Calc
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_GD_Group AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID, A.GD_ID;


    -- Output without Sample Size
    --Select * from dbo.#Rescu_Level_Calc;
    --Select * from dbo.#PR_Level_Calc;
    --Select * from dbo.#GD_Level_Calc;

    --=================================================

    -- Get Distinct Combination from Closed Data for Provided Rescue ID at RESCU Leval
    Select  RESCU_ID
            , Combine_ID
    into    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample
    from    dbo.#OpenData
    GROUP BY RESCU_ID, Combine_ID;

    -- Get sum of Sample Size for Provided Rescue ID at RESCU Level
    Select  A.RESCU_ID
            , SUM(ISNULL(B.SampleSize,0)) AS SampleSize
            --, B.SampleSize
    INTO    dbo.#RESCU_Sample
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID;

    --------------------------------------------------

    -- Get Distinct Combination from Closed Data for Provided Rescue ID at PR Leval
    SELECT  RESCU_ID
            , PR_ID
            , Combine_ID
    INTO    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_PR
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData
    GROUP BY RESCU_ID, PR_ID, Combine_ID;

    -- Get sum of Sample Size for Provided Rescue ID at PR Level
    Select  A.RESCU_ID
            , A.PR_ID
            , SUM(ISNULL(B.SampleSize,0)) AS SampleSize
    INTO    dbo.#PR_Sample
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_PR AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID;


    --------------------------------------------------

    -- Get Distinct Combination from Closed Data for Provided Rescue ID at GD Leval
    SELECT  RESCU_ID
            , PR_ID
            , GD_ID
            , Combine_ID
    INTO    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_GD
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData
    GROUP BY RESCU_ID, PR_ID, GD_ID, Combine_ID;

    -- Get sum of Sample Size for Provided Rescue ID at PR Level
    Select  A.RESCU_ID
            , A.PR_ID
            , A.GD_ID
            , SUM(ISNULL(B.SampleSize,0)) AS SampleSize
    INTO    dbo.#GD_Sample
    FROM    dbo.#OpenData_RESCU_Group_Sample_GD AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedDataResult AS B
                ON A.Combine_ID = B.Combine_ID
    GROUP BY A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID, A.GD_ID;
    --=================================================

    -- Final Output with Sample Size

    -- RECSU LEVEL
    Select  A.RESCU_ID, A.RESCU_Create_Date, A.Total_PRs, A.Total_GDs, A.MIN_TAT, A.MAX_TAT, B.SampleSize
    from    dbo.#Rescu_Level_Calc AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.#RESCU_Sample AS B
                ON A.RESCU_ID = B.RESCU_ID;

    -- PR LEVEL
    Select  A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID, A.Total_GDs, A.MIN_TAT, A.MAX_TAT, B.SampleSize
    from    dbo.#PR_Level_Calc AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.#PR_Sample AS B
                ON A.RESCU_ID = B.RESCU_ID
                AND A.PR_ID = B.PR_ID;

    -- GD LEVEL 
    Select  A.RESCU_ID, A.PR_ID, A.GD_ID, A.MIN_TAT, A.MAX_TAT, B.SampleSize
    from    dbo.#GD_Level_Calc AS A
            LEFT JOIN dbo.#GD_Sample AS B
                ON A.RESCU_ID = B.RESCU_ID
                AND A.PR_ID = B.PR_ID
                AND A.GD_ID = B.GD_ID;

END


EXEC [dbo].[CrystalBall_TAT_Computation] '19993-19993'
```

Above is my stored procedure. How can I implement this?

[This is the result of stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVEk.png)